# Inserting a new column into a dataframes gives 'ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (6)'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I created a dataframe with the pandas library. I want to add a column to the dataframe. However I am getting the following error.But I think I have to enter as much data as the number of lines.How can I enter information in the row and column I want? How can I create a column without entering data?

```
import pandas as pd

kd = pd.DataFrame(data) 
insertColumns = kd.insert(0, "Age", [21, 23, 24, 21],True ) 
print(kd)
```

error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (6)
```

Comment: `kd["new_col"]=None`? should put None in all rows

Comment: Thank you very very very very much for your help. It happened the way you wrote it.

Comment: my last question. :) How can I do this if I need to adjust the column's order?

Comment: `df.insert(0,"Age", None, True)` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you insert too few rows. Your dataframe contains 6 rows, you only add 4 values in your insert statement. If you add a new column with data, it has to match the current length:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"1":list(range(6))})
df.insert(0, "Age", [21, 23, 24, 21],True )
# Length of values does not match length of index
```

You can add a new empty column like so:

```
df["new_col"] = None

# or

df.insert(0,"Age", None, True)  # to get a new colum at position 0 all None
```

or "trick" pandas by list slicing the given data and append enough Nones at end:

```
# extend the data you want to give by a None-List and slice the whole down to size
df.insert(0,"Age", ([21,23,24,21] + [None]*len(df))[:len(df)], True)
```

to get

```
    Age  1
0  21.0  0
1  23.0  1
2  24.0  2
3  21.0  3
4   NaN  4   # only 2 None appends needed 
5   NaN  5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, no matter how hard I try, sometimes my head hangs. I am searching a lot, actually. However, my English is not very good.but the codes speak the same language. Still this helps me. I will work harder. one day I'll help other people like those who helped me.Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

this works

```
kd = pd.DataFrame(data) 
kd["col_name"]=[21, 23, 24, 21]
```

for this u need to make sure that the length of list is equal to number of rows.
if some rows are empty u need to do this

```
kd["col_name"]=[21,None, 23, 24,None, 21]
```

for entering information in desired row and column u can do this as below

```
kd.loc["index_name","col_name"]=value
```